# Web scraping from Yahoo Finance: cannot access individual tabs within a web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data from Yahoo Finance (using the BeautifulSoup-library of Python). Everything works fine unless I try to obtain data from a tab within the page, where the **tab is not loaded by default**.

Consider, for example, the page https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/financials?p=GOOG&.tsrc=fin-srch which has a tab *Annual* (loaded by default) and a tab *Quarterly*.

Accessing data from the tab *Annual* is not a problem. It is the tab loaded by default. However, I have no idea how to access data from the tab *Quarterly*. Indeed, it seems that the underlying HTML-code of the page does not provide a specific line of code which can be used by the programmer as an anchor to access either the one or the other tab.

Below I have provided screenshots of the HTML-code of the tab *Annual* and of the tab *Quarterly* (showing revenue of 12/31/2018 and of 6/30/2019 at the bottom). The underlying code of both tabs is identical except of the finance number.

Can anyone provide a solution how to load data from the tab *Quarterly*?

[HTML-code for tab "Annular"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyRdi.png)

[HTML-code for tab "Quarterly"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPce2.png)

Comment: A request is sent in order to get that tab loaded. Consider using `requests` to load that page. 

After clicking on "quarterly" I realized this request was sent 

```
https://fc.yahoo.com/sdarla/php/fc.php?tID=3&d=0&f=95993639&l=FB2A%2CFB2B%2CFB2C%2CFB2D%2CLDRB%2CLDRB2%2CMON%2CLREC%2CLREC2%2CFOOT%2CFSRVY&rn=1567281494401&en=utf-8&lang=en-US&filter=no_exp.......
```

Comment: It's not the full request. I couldn't post the full thing. But I hope that gives you an idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is already present. It is simply loaded from a script tag when you click. You can regex out the appropriate string and parse with json library. You will need to study the json to determine which access paths to use. The data is within

```
data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
```

Examples below:

```
import requests, re, json

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')
r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/financials?p=GOOG&.tsrc=fin-srch&guccounter=1')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
quote_store = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
print(quote_store['earnings']['financialsChart']['quarterly'])
print(quote_store['incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly']['incomeStatementHistory'])
```

You can quick view the sections:

[image]

Comment: hi, is there a question? That value is not currently present in quarterly figures.

Comment: Thanks! I apply the following method. 
Revenue data is situated at the tag  _<td class="Fz(s) Ta(end) Pstart(10px)"><span>167,362,000</span></td>_

I write every number situated at class _Fz(s) Ta(end) Pstart(10px)_ into an array and would expect that both annular and quarterly data shows up in the array. But only annular data shows up. Here is the code:

response = opener.open('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/financials?p=GOOG&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
base = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'Fz(s) Ta(end) Pstart(10px)'})
revenue_18 = base[0].text

Comment: have a look at my answer the values are all present in that json  167,362,000 is not present on the page

Comment: Thanks again! In the meantime, I have tested your code. Indeed, all quarterly numbers are present. 
Your way for extracting finance numbers is different (and probably more efficient) than my method. You use the libraries "requests", "re" and "json" while my way of extracting is based on "BeautifulSoup". In order to understand your method better, I have two follow up questions:
1. In your code, are you using commands of the Yahoo API?
2. What would I have to modify in your code in order to obtain the annual numbers? Just changing the keyword 'quarterly' to 'annually' does not work.

Comment: Hi 1) I am not using commands of API 2) you would need to examine the Json to see where annual numbers are stored.  Pasting Json into a Json viewer with search facility is a quick and easy to search for specific values and see the paths required. Looks like probably in sections that include annual in key

Comment: These paths should be the same across tickets. You could also look at any recursive functions for emptying Json